# Polymer Element gets corrupted dimensions when stamped within a template with dynamic HTML Import

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

This is a bit composite case, but in does not occur in more isolated ones.

I have created two custom elements:

1. `<my-element>` (Polymer) that needs to know its width when stamped to DOM (originally it was [juicy-tile-list](http://github.com/Juicy/juicy-tile-list))

   [my-element.html](https://github.com/tomalec/templates_vs_htmlimports-issue/blob/gh-pages/components/my-element.html#L26)

   ```
   Polymer('my-element', ( {
     domReady: function (){
       this.width = this.offsetWidth;
   ```
2. `<dynamic-import>` (VanillaJS) that adds HTML Import (`<link>` tag to the head) when attached (originally [imported-template](http://github.com/Juicy/imported-template)), and does not change element's DOM at all.

   [dynamic-import.html](https://github.com/tomalec/templates_vs_htmlimports-issue/blob/gh-pages/components/dynamic-import.html#L16)

   ```
   DynamicImportPrototype.attachedCallback = function () {
     // create new link tag
     // ...
     document.head.appendChild(link);
   };
   ```

Then I simply pack those to `<template>`:

[index.html](https://github.com/tomalec/templates_vs_htmlimports-issue/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L21)

```
...
<template bind>
      <my-element>
          <dynamic-import></dynamic-import>
      </my-element>
  </template>
```

Full [demo is here](http://tomalec.github.io/templates_vs_htmlimports-issue/)

---

In Canary (native HTML Imports support?) `this.offsetWidth` is `0`, but for empty `<div>` with style `width: 100%`, it should be container - `<body>` - width.

Under Chrome Stable, and IE it works fine, it also gets corrected after few ms.
Removing wrapping `<template>` fixes initial width, as well as removing `document.head.appendChild` line. How and why adding node to the head, affects elements size? Is this a bug in Polymer, Canary, or in my code? Is there any nice solution?

Answer (score 2):

It look like a Chrome bug. [Polymer GH issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/554#issuecomment-47359848), [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389566)

However I found a temporary workaround - remove dynamic import from attaching flow:

```
DynamicImportPrototype.attachedCallback = function () {
  // create new link tag
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = "import";
  link.href = "components/whatever.html";
  // add it to the head
  setTimeout( function asyncImport(){
      document.head.appendChild(link);
  });
};
```

Then measuring should happen before import will be added.
Doing it other way around would require wait for import to continue rendering, which not only be hard to implement, but could heavily affect UX.